# Well Formed JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I am attempting to set up a local json file that I can use to mock some data for axios for a vuejs project i am working on.

Following this guide 
https://medium.com/@negarjf/how-to-access-a-static-json-file-in-vue-cli-3-8943dc343f95

everything seems to work except my json file is returning the data as one big string?

My JSON file looks like this....

```
[{label: "Assamese", count: 13},
{label: "Bengali", count: 83},
{label: "Bodo", count: 1.4},
{label: "Dogri", count: 2.3},
{label: "Gujarati", count: 46},
{label: "Hindi", count: 300},
{label: "Kannada", count: 38},
{label: "Kashmiri", count: 5.5},
{label: "Konkani", count: 5},
{label: "Maithili", count: 20},
{label: "Malayalam", count: 33},
{label: "Manipuri", count: 1.5},
{label: "Marathi", count: 72},
{label: "Nepali", count: 2.9},
{label: "Oriya", count: 33},
{label: "Punjabi", count: 29},
{label: "Sanskrit", count: 0.01},
{label: "Santhali", count: 6.5},
{label: "Sindhi", count: 2.5},
{label: "Tamil", count: 61},
{label: "Telugu", count: 74},
{label: "Urdu", count: 52}]
```

however my console.log is showing me JSON that looks like this...

```
{label: "Assamese", count: 13},
{label: "Bengali", count: 83},
{label: "Bodo", count: 1.4},
{label: "Dogri", count: 2.3},
{label: "Gujarati", count: 46},
{label: "Hindi", count: 300},
{label: "Kannada", count: 38},
{label: "Kashmiri", count: 5.5},
{label: "Konkani", count: 5},
{label: "Maithili", count: 20},
{label: "Malayalam", count: 33},
{label: "Manipuri", count: 1.5},
{label: "Marathi", count: 72},
{label: "Nepali", count: 2.9},
{label: "Oriya", count: 33},
{label: "Punjabi", count: 29},
{label: "Sanskrit", count: 0.01},
{label: "Santhali", count: 6.5},
{label: "Sindhi", count: 2.5},
{label: "Tamil", count: 61},
{label: "Telugu", count: 74},
{label: "Urdu", count: 52}
```

As you can see my data is being treated as a string instead of well formed json.

Any idea why?

**UPDATE** 
As requested, this is the axios code I run in my vue file

```
let dataset = [];
        console.log(this.baseUrl);
        axios.get(this.baseUrl + '/mockdata/pie-chart-data.json').then(response => {
            dataset = response.data;
            console.log(response.data);
        })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log('axios error', e)
            });
```

**Update 2**
I updated my response.data

It's literally just giving me the json as a string, im not seeing it as a json tree in the firefox console.

Comment: Can you share some code? JSON is just string data until you parse it (JSON.parse). Many libraries that work with Ajax stuff have ways to do that for you.

Comment: so "response.data` is what you are logging? your server is sending the wrong thing in that case - can you give some details of your http server

Comment: See Update.....

Comment: yes response.data is what I am logging. I can see it as a string when it is logged, but not as a JSON  tree.

Comment: Why have you changed the output you are seeing? let me guess ... you originally showed the result of `console.log(response)`

Comment: Yes my server is http://localhost:8080/ 

When I do a console.log(this.baseUrl); that is the response it gives me

Comment: @JaromandaX yes it was originally just response. When I changed it to response.data that is the result. It's only giving me text, not a JSON tree

Comment: ok ... did you write the server code? perhaps it's JSON.stringifying the file content before sending it

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I wrote the JSON file above and placed it in my public/mockdata folder. I needed to have some mock data to work with until I get access to the APIs I will eventually use.

Comment: I asked if you wrote the http server (it looked like it was nodejs express) - I know you wrote the file, because you said that in the question ...

Comment: @Jamie It isn't valid JSON, the property keys need to be in double quotes. e.g. `"label"` and `"count"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are making an http request to fetch the .json file and then you are logging the entire response that you are getting back to the console. So the 'data' field is the actual file contents, and the entire object you are logging to console is the whole http request being made.

[Update]
Since you are now logging response.data which is a string, parse the string into an object like so:

```
var json = JSON.parse(response.data);
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that so that my code looks like console.log(JSON.parse(response.data))

And I get the following error.

SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

Comment: @skirtle

I think that may be the problem but now I am getting a different error. I literally stripped my JSON file down to one object.

{"label": "Assamese", "count": 13}

and now I get the following
axios error SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

Comment: Yep that was the problem, Axios parses it for me, so when I removed the JSON.parse it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need console `data` from response.

For example:

```
let res = await axios.get(
    'https://...'
  );
 console.log(res.data)
```